# Add to VSCode autocorrect dictionary to address common mistake

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocorrect, misspelling

I consistently misspell `const` (due to permanent injury and missing bones in my right hand) when I type too fast with one hand and not the other. I'd like to find how to tell VSCode that `cosnt` should always be changed to `const`, hopefully as a custom case added to whatever dictionary that is built-in.

I've hoped to rely on at least having the misspell highlighted as an error. It doesn't get recognized as a mistake though.

// what it looks like (again, never marked as erroneous)

```
cosnt foo = 'bar';
```

// I'm just hoping to add a simple setting to say, "When you see 'cosnt' always change it to 'const'.

```
const foo = 'bar';
```

Comment: I'd like if it were a built-in setting I could add to. But, I don't know why I didn't see that post before. I scrolled-through all the suggestions before posting. The linked answer will help, but I'd like to find there is a, "autocorrect.dictionary" or the like built-in. Thanks though, @rinkert

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in setting at the moment (or very well hidden?). Closest thing would be a snippet, but then you'd have to press enter instead of space. You can always make a feature request on the [vscode github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues).